# Applying Clifford operator in tableaux form to my stabilizer state

Tags: qiskit, stabilizer-code, clifford-group

I was reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.09412.pdf) and referring to the source codes of `qiskit.quantum_info.random_clifford` to build a random circuit that applies random Clifford operator on my initial state. Once I tried

```
quantum_info.random_clifford(2)
```

to draw a random Clifford operator that acts of 2 qubits, it resulted tableaux form:

```
Clifford(array([[False,  True,  True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True, False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True, False,  True]]))
```

which is in stabilizer tableaux form but how can I use it to apply the random operator to my initial state tableaux, for example in this form:

```
Clifford(array([[True , False, False, False, False],
                [False, True , False, False, False],
                [False, False, True , False, False],
                [False, False, False, True , False]]))
```

which is $|00 \rangle$ state?